# image buffer implementation in delphi

Tags: delphi, image, canvas, drawing, buffer

**Context**

I am drawing to a canvas, this is updated regularly and it flashes.
Logically thinking I assumed this is because my redraw method clears the Canvas then draws one element at a time to the canvas. so my idea was to write to a Timage then set the picture to the Timage.

---

**Information**

here is my code

```
procedure Tmainwindow.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var bufferpicture:TImage;
begin

//draw stuff to bufferpicture
  //***
//draw stuff to bufferpicture

myrealpicture.picture:=bufferpicture.picture;

end;
```

Upon running the code I get a error show below.
[image]

---

**Question**
How do I set the canvas of one to another since canvas is a read only property? or is there a better way to do what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It looks like you did not create `myrealpicture`
2. I would use the method `Assign`

   `MyRealPicture.Picture.Assign(BufferPicture.Picture);`
3. You can copy the content of one canvas to another using `BitBlt`:

   ```
   var
     BackBuffer: TBitmap;
   begin
     BackBuffer := TBitmap.Create;
     try
       { drawing stuff goes here}
       BitBlt(Form1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BackBuffer.Width, BackBuffer.Height,
           BackBuffer.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
     finally
       BackBuffer.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. You can just use the `DoubleBuffered` property

Answer (score 3):

use the `DoubleBuffered` property